# Python execute command in console

Tags: python, console, subprocess

I'm trying to make a program that takes a command and executes it in the console of any operating system and prints the response in python. For this I'm using `subprocess.check_output`. The program works fine with the  `ipconfig` command (I'm on windows), and the response gets printed after no time. With the `notepad` command, it opens notepad and only continues when I close notepad. Is it possible to just continue without notepad being closed?

Code:

```
import subprocess


def executeCommand(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command).decode('ISO-8859-1')


def cmdCommand(command):
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
    asynch_result = pool.apply_async(executeCommand, [command])
    for i in range(3):
        if asynch_result.get() is not None:
            return asynch_result.get()
        sleep(1)
    pool.terminate()
    return "No result gotten"


print(cmdCommand("ipconfig"))
print(cmdCommand("notepad"))
```

Comment: 1) `check_output` is specifically made to **wait** for the process to finish and return its output, if you don't want that, don't use `check_output`, 2) What python version is this? `check_output` is an old API, you should not use this with newer versions of `subprocess` 3) You're looking for [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

Comment: also why are you using `ThreadPool` here? Not only is it an old API, it also seems very useless in this case. It's just turning a simple and regular blocking method into a much more complicated and less robust but **still blocking** method

Comment: You can create a new thread for each command or use "subprocess.Popen" or see https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-subprocess.html for asyncio's support of subprocesses.